# Playing fly from library using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flv, flvplayback

How can I play a video from my library using AS3? It is in folder `video` and is called `video01.flv`.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.video.*;

    public class video01 extends MovieClip
    {
        public function video01()
        {
            trace("movieclip 1 geladen");
            btn_terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, terug);
        }

        public function terug(evt:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            trace("knop ingedrukt");
            Main(parent).filmAan = false;
            this.parent.removeChild(this);    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Its as easy as this:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.video.*;

public class video01 extends MovieClip
{
    public function video01()
    {
        videoPlayer.source = "video/video01.flv";
        trace("movieclip 1 geladen");
        btn_terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, terug);
    }

    public function terug(evt:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("knop ingedrukt");
        Main(parent).filmAan = false;
        this.parent.removeChild(this);  
    }
}
}
```